# ContextBridge remains undefined in preload.js giving error: Cannot read property 'exposeInMainWorld' of undefined in packaged Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I have an angular application wrapped in Electron. I have generated the installer using electron-builder. As per the recommendations for communication with renderer process I have used `preload.js` as `preload` script.

The script works fine in the development environment. However, once I package the app and install it, it shows me the error **Cannot read property 'exposeInMainWorld' of undefined**

Here is my `preload.js`

```
window.onload = () => {
    const {
        contextBridge,
        ipcRenderer
    } = require("electron");

    const validChannels = ['event-1', 'event-2', 'event-3'];

    // Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
        "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels To Main Process
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            // From Main Process
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                console.log('receive: ' + channel);
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
    );
};
```

**My Main.js**

```
        this._win = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 1024,
            height: 768,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: false,
                webSecurity: true,
                allowEval: false,
                allowRunningInsecureContent: false,
                contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
                enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
                preload: path.join(__dirname, "./preload.js") // use a preload script
            },
            title: this._appTitle,
            autoHideMenuBar: true,
            icon: path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/some-path/favicon.ico')
        });
```

I have kept both `main.js` and `preload.js` inside a folder electron at the root level where `package.json` is available. In case you need to check my `builder-config.yaml`, it's present at [this link](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/5156#issue-662121869).

Please suggest what to do.

**P.S. : the `preload.js` works absolutely fine while in dev mode. The issue is only after packaging the app with electron-builder**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this one working. Actually the version of electron mentioned in my `builder-config.yaml` was `5.0.13`. The `contextbridge` api was not introduced then. When I changed the version of electron to 9 and above, it works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this kind of error when I wrote:

```js
getPlatform: () => window.remote.getPlatform(),
```

Then I get `Uncaught Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlatform' of undefined`

in

```
console.log('window.remote.getPlatform()', window.remote.getPlatform && window.remote?.getPlatform())
```

When I change it to

```
getPlatform: () => process.platform,
```

everything works just fine.

Comment: The problem that I am facing is that everything works just fine when I run the app in development using `electron .` command. I am getting this issue only after the app is packaged using `electron-builder`.

Does anyone know if `electron-builder` lacks support for **contextbuilder** ?